# Easy way to mention all the objects inside a function without explicitly writing all of them

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

Suppose I have created 100 data frames by the name of v1, v2, v3, v4, v5,...,v99,v100. 
All these data frames are of the same size, I mean they all have the same set of columns.
I now want to export all these data frames appended in a single csv file using rbind within write.csv.
So I am using the function

```
write.csv(rbind(v1, v2, v3,v4,v5), "myfilename.csv")
```

The above command does the job but as you can see only 5 data frames are appended. I want to append all the data frames i.e. from v1 to v100 (in a sequential order ) but writing all of their names individually can be a painful task. Is there an easy way to mention all the object names without writing all of their names. Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: Well, creating them as a bunch of different variables wasn't a great idea in the first place. Better to do which things in a list. How did you create them in the first place? There are ways to do what you want but it's probably better to fix the problem at the start when clean up after the mess later.

Comment: These data frames contains the decile binning information for all my continuous variables in my data set. I want to put all these decile information in a single worksheet so that I can review it and do profiling which is needed for a regression modelling task. This is the reason I have to use rbind function and mention all these object names from v1 to say v100. Hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must have separate objects then get the names and order them by number. Then copy them into list `L` and `rbind` them together

```
nms <- ls(pattern = "^v\\d+$")
nms <- nms[order(as.numeric(sub("v", "", nms)))]
L <- mget(nms)
DF <- do.call("rbind", L)
```

however, as @MrFlick mentioned it would have been better to create them in a list `L` in the first place in which case only the last statement would be needed.